# Confused over compareTo implementation with PriorityQueue

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue, compareto

I am trying to write a program where I replicate a registrar's office using a priority queue. The sorting for this priority queue would be based on a higher GPA being served first etc. I have constructed a program that does this with my own implementation but I am simply confused how to implement my compareTo method.

```
//Create Priority Queue
PriorityQueue<Student> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Student>(10, compareTo());
```

First I made my priority queue. According to documentation, I can specify what I am to use for my comparisons, compareTo().

But when I tried to implement my compareTo method, it does not allow me to provide any parameters.

```
private Comparator<? super Student> compareTo(Student x, Student y) {
}
```

It tells me 'compareTo in BursarOfficeJavaService cannot be applied to ()' and my IDE offers to remove my parameters. But I do not understand how I can make comparisons without objects to compare?

My only other method in the class is recieveEvent, which basically just determines if I am removing from the queue or adding to the queue. The data under the event is a student object I can compare with, but I simply don't understand how to put this all together.

```
    public void receiveEvent(Event<Student> event) {
    if (event.getType() == EventType.REQUEST_COMPLETED){
        pQueue.poll();
    }

    else{


    }
}
```

With some help, I have come up with this compare method. However an issue still persists when a new student is checked against the student first on the list, and their GPA is not higher, it will append that student to the end of the list without checking against the other students in the pQueue.

```
PriorityQueue<Student> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Student>(10, new Comparator<Student>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2){
        if (o1.equals(o2))
            return 0;
        else if(o1.getGpa() > o2.getGpa())
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }

});

private boolean equals (Student o1, Student o2){
    if (o1.getGpa() == o2.getGpa())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: You have to provide a `Comparator` instance. Implement a class with `Comparator<Student>` and pass an instance of it in the `PriorityQueue` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Create new Class which implements `Comparator` Inteface and pass this class instance to your priority queue.

If your GPA is Class/Reference Type:(e.g. Integer,Double,Float) you can use following code :

```
PriorityQueue<Student> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Student>(10, new Comparator<Student> (){

    @Override
    public int compare(Student arg0, Student arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0.getGPA().compareTo(arg1.getGPA());
    }
});
```

If your GPA is primitive Type:(e.g. int,double,float) you can use following code :

```
@Override
    public int compare(Student arg0, Student arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Integer.compare(arg0.getGPA(),arg1.getGPA());
    }
```

**Note:** Replace Integer according to your datatype.

`compareTo()` doesn't necessarily return only -1, 0 or 1. `compareTo()`return 0 for both objects are equal, value less than zero if obj1 < obj2 and value greater than zero if obj1 > obj2.
This method is inline comparator declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I have created such a compare method and posted it above with my logic.

I do still have an issue that has arose where when a new student is being added to the list, it will compare to the first student in my pQueue and if their GPA is not higher than the student at the top of my list, they are sent down to the bottom without being compared to any other students in my list.

If you can think of anything I would much appreciate it!

Comment: I have updated the code. You can use according to your datatype of GPA

Comment: You are missing "()" after new Comparator<Student>

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter expects a Comparator object, not a direct call to the compareTo Method:

```
//Create Priority Queue
PriorityQueue<Student> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Student>(10, new Comparator<Student>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            // your logic
        }
    });
```

The "compare(T o1, T o2)"-Method is part of that Comparator object and has to be defined in one.

Comment: Currently in a class. This makes sense though and I'll report back later when I work on in. Thanks!

Comment: So this worked well for me! Thank you for that.

However I have ran into another issue and maybe you can explain it to me.

I am comparing these students based on their GPA. And when I step through my program it will take a new student being added to my pQueue and compare it to the student first in my list, but if my new students GPA is not higher than the student top on my list it will go ahead and put it at the end of my pQueue without checking against the other students in my list.

I have added my compare method above...